# Can't get VueJS 3 component to work from CDN (Standalone)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I've been trying to get [this plugin](https://github.com/RealRobin-com/vue3-timeago) to work in a single standalone html project with only using `<script>` from CDN. I've tried just including the script but that return `Vue.component is not a function` or `TimeAgo is not a function`. <strike>Found [this article](https://medium.com/@jamesweee/using-vue-js-single-file-component-without-module-bundlers-aea58d892ad9#295a) that uses `http-vue-loader` and couldn't get it to work either.</strike>

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. All the examples assume the use of npm/bundler. Coming from jQuery where you can just add `<script>` tags to Vue has been difficult.

Thanks!

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
} = Vue;

const App = {
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Hello from Vue',
    }
  },
  components:{
    TimeAgo //Err: "TimeAgo is not defined"
  }
}

createApp(App).mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue3-timeago@1.0.6/dist/vue3-timeago.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <time-ago :refresh="60" :datetime="new Date(2018, 7, 4, 0, 24, 0)" tooltip></time-ago>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s the syntax for Vue2. You’re using Vue3, which requires a different way of globally registering your component: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration

Comment: @Terry thanks! I tried that and still get `TimeAgo is not defined`... the page you referenced uses `import`. I'm not using bundler... I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: `vue3-timeago` does not actually work with Vue 3, despite the `vue3-` in its name (see [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-timeago-broken?file=src/App.vue)). It [depends on `vue-template-compiler`](https://github.com/RealRobin-com/vue3-timeago/blob/bdd87bf/package.json#L31), which compiles templates for Vue 2.

Comment: @tony19 thanks! I was able to find [vue2-timeago V2](https://github.com/runkids/vue2-timeago) which supports Vue 3 but now I get `Uncaught TypeError: c.use is not a function
` I'm giving up... back to vanilla js it is